# PowerBI .pbix DataMashup Compressed Directory

Tags: python, powerbi, 7zip, pkzip

I am attempting to inspect a PowerBI `.pbix` file using python's `zipfile` library.

When unzipping the `.pbix` archive, I get the following structure:

```
DataMashup
DataModel
DiagramLayout
Metadata
Report
ReporLayout
ReporStaticResources
ReporStaticResourceSharedResources
ReporStaticResourceSharedResourceBaseThemes
ReporStaticResourceSharedResourceBaseThemeCY18SU07.json
SecurityBindings
Settings
Version
[Content_Types].xml
```

It appears that the `DataMashup` file in the `.pbix` archive is some sort of off-brand archive of a directory.

The `DataMashup` object does not appear to be compressed, as I can easily read `xml` data when printing the object in the python interpreter.

Using `7zip` I am able to access everything within:

```
DataMashup/
    Config/
        Package.xml
    Formulas/
        Section1.m # m and/or dax looking stuff
[Content_Types].xml
```

How can I discover the format of the `DataMashup` archive-within-an-archive?

One clue is in the binary data at the top of the `DataMashup` object: `\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x05\x00\x00PK` which may indicate pkzip.

Another clue may be this output when attempting to use `unzip` on the `DataMashup` file:

```sh
$ unzip DataMashup
Archive:  DataMashup
warning [DataMashup]:  6215 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
```

I was able to uncompress the `DataMashup` directory on linux using `7za`:

```sh
WARNINGS:
There are data after the end of archive

--
Path = DataMashup
Type = zip
WARNINGS:
There are data after the end of archive
Offset = 8
Physical Size = 1303
Tail Size = 5148

Everything is Ok

Archives with Warnings: 1

Warnings: 1
Files: 3
Size:       2040
Compressed: 6459
```

Despite the warnings, the files appear okay. Unfortunately, this does not help me on windows.

Comment: I can find the metadata format here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-qdeff/e6377721-700b-411c-9d4f-3fc02472454b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pbix files are zipped, so one need to unzip the file. DataMashup follows the [MS-QDEFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-qdeff/27b1dd1e-7de8-45d9-9c84-dfcc7a802e37) spec.

The DataMashup file within the archive is also an archive, it contains Section1.m which has the query source definitions

1. change file section1.m
2. repackage DataMashup
3. rezip and change the extension back to xlsx

here a really good tutorial in c#

https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/8acb9f29-4b28-400b-b8df-cbe523edcb01/y

and another here, using power shell

https://querypower.medium.com/extracting-power-queries-41fd73d3d6a2

Comment: Thanks! Shortly after posting (and forgetting) this question, I had started using .pbit (power bi template) files to get most of what I wanted. This may help me fill in some corners.